# Query is giving invalid character (ORA-00911: invalid character)issue

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

If i execute below query then i am getting **invalid character.**

```
declare
sql_query varchar2(4000):='delete from ';
begin
for i in (
select table_name,column_name from User_tab_cols where column_name like '%PROFILE_ID' and table_name not like 'GSC%' and table_name not like '%BKP%' order by 1)
loop
sql_query :=sql_query ||i.table_name;
sql_query:=sql_query || ' where '||i.column_name ||' = ' ||32052721 ||';';
execute immediate  sql_query;
commit;
end loop;
end;
```

Kindly help me on this issue.

Many thanks for your help.

I am using Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 version.

Comment: May be you receive multiple rows in for loop select? If so, you need to append 'delete from ' every time.

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the end of your `sql_query` string. That's the immediate problem. But you are also need to start the whole command again in each loop, as Mikhail showed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.I have tried Mikhail option but still getting same issue like Invalid character. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you need to initiate sql_query for every iteration of the loop. For example, like this:

```
declare
sql_query varchar2(4000);
begin
for i in (
select table_name,column_name from User_tab_cols where column_name like '%PROFILE_ID' and table_name not like 'GSC%' and table_name not like '%BKP%' order by 1)
loop
sql_query :='delete from ';
sql_query :=sql_query ||i.table_name;
sql_query:=sql_query || ' where '||i.column_name ||' = 32052721';
execute immediate  sql_query;
commit;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But still i am getting same error like ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 10. Please help me.Many thanks.

Comment: @Sunitha In what environment are you trying to execute this? sqlplus, sql developer or something else? Try adding the line with / at the end of the script, if this is sqlplus.

Comment: @Sunitha Just have tested it - works without errors. Have you removed the semicolon at the end of sql_query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: There is an additional '`;`' in your dynamic string.

Here:

> sql_query:=sql_query || ' where '||i.column_name ||' = ' ||32052721
>   ||';';

```
DECLARE
   sql_query   VARCHAR2 (4000) := 'delete from ';
BEGIN
   FOR i
      IN (  SELECT table_name, column_name
              FROM User_tab_cols
             WHERE     column_name LIKE '%PROFILE_ID'
                   AND table_name NOT LIKE 'GSC%'
                   AND table_name NOT LIKE '%BKP%'
          ORDER BY 1)
   LOOP
      sql_query := sql_query || i.table_name;
      sql_query :=
         sql_query || ' where ' || i.column_name || ' = ' || 32052721 ;

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query;
       Sql_query:=' ';
      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialize your query on each loop, and omit the trailing semicolon.

```
DECLARE
    l_sql_query   VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (  SELECT table_name, column_name
                  FROM user_tab_cols
                 WHERE column_name LIKE '%PROFILE_ID'
                   AND table_name NOT LIKE 'GSC%'
                   AND table_name NOT LIKE '%BKP%'
              ORDER BY 1)
    LOOP
        l_sql_query   := ' delete from ' || i.table_name || ' where ' || i.column_name || ' = ' || 32052721;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_query;

        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
```